# way to update wkinterfacecontroller during runtime in watch os 2

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

In Header file

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>

@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController<WCSessionDelegate>
- (IBAction)lastSongButtonClick;
- (IBAction)playSongButtonClick;
- (IBAction)nextSongButtonClick;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *songTitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceButton *playSongButton;

@end
```

So I implemented the WCSessionDelegate and every time I receive about the UI, I would want it to update. So in my .m file I have:

```
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message{
    NSString* type = [message objectForKey:@"type"];
    if([type isEqualToString:@"UIUpdateInfo"]){
        NSLog(@"Watch receives UI update info");
        [self handleUIUpdateInfo:[message objectForKey:@"content"]];
    }
}
```

AND

```
- (void)handleUIUpdateInfo:(NSDictionary*)updateInfo{
    [self.songTitleLabel setText:[updateInfo objectForKey:@"nowPlayingSongTitle"]];
    [self.playSongButton setBackgroundImage:[updateInfo objectForKey:@"playButtonImage"]];
}
```

However, it doesn't seems to update. Is there any proper way to update?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're halfway there. You've configured receiving the message on the watch side correctly, but you'll need to trigger a message to be sent when the UI is updated (therefore triggering `didReceiveMessage` to execute and update the appropriate content).

Where ever you are making changes to the UI, you'll need to include this:

```
NSDictionary *message = //dictionary of info you want to send
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:message
                           replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {
                               //handle reply didReceiveMessage here
                           }
                           errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                               //catch any errors here
                           }
 ];
```

Also, make sure you're activating the `WCSession` properly. This is usually done in `viewDidLoad` or `willAppear` depending on whether you're implementing this on the phone or the watch.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }
}
```

You can see a full example of an end-to-end Watch to iPhone data transfer in this tutorial - http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-tutorial-using-sendmessage-for-instantaneous-data-transfer-watch-connectivity-1

Comment: OMG! You are the author for this tutorial?http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/ I saw your tutorial and totally nailed it for my own application actually. I got the receiving part right, as well as the activating WCSession part and sendingMessage part right, even though I didn't post them in my question! It's just inside the sendingMessage part, I messed up my NSDictionary message, since i am new to objective c and didn't know that NSDictionary cannot handle UIImage*. So sendMessage part is revoked but no actual message send out. TY!

Comment: Yup, that's me :) Yeah, only types that can be serialized can go into the dictionary. For future reference, these are NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray and NSDictionary. Glad it worked out!

Comment: Cool! Again, thanks a lot for this tutorial and the answer here. I am the only developer in our team and since watch os 2 just came out, not much online for me to find and learn. Yours saved me!

Comment: I'd recommend doing the activation of the WCSession in a part of your code that also gets executed when the apps are running in the background (viewDidLoad and willAppear do not get called unless the UI is actually shown).